# Wagtail custom template at route

Tags: django, wagtail

How would I add a custom template to a page when using RoutablePageMixin?

```
@route(r'^tag/(?P<tag>[-\w]+)/$')
def post_by_tag(self, request, tag, *args, **kwargs):
    self.search_type = 'tag'
    self.search_term = tag
    self.posts = self.get_posts().filter(tags__slug=tag)
    return Page.serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the `django.shortcuts.render` function, as you would in [a standard Django view function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render):

```
from django.shortcuts import render

@route(r'^tag/(?P<tag>[-\w]+)/$')
def post_by_tag(self, request, tag, *args, **kwargs):
    # ...
    posts = self.get_posts().filter(tags__slug=tag)
    return render(request, 'path/to/template.html', {
        'page': self,
        'posts': posts,
    })
```

Comment: Fantastic! I completely forgot about that. Thanks a lot!